# Can´t get the SQL DATEDIFF output to int - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

When i'm trying to parse my DATEDIFF in a int, it comes out with "Input string was not in a correct format".

it works with the other SQL output, but that´s not a DATEDIFF.

I had tried to CAST and CONVERT it, but still get the same error.

```
" CAST((DATEDIFF(SECOND, start_time, stop_time)) AS int) AS Frokost " +

int frokost = int.Parse(row["Frokost"].ToString());

  @if (frokost >= 1800)
  {
      <td style="background-color:red;"><b>@row["Frokost"]</b></td>
  }
  else
  {
      <td style="background-color:limegreen;"><b>@row["Frokost"]</b></td>
  }
```

Comment: (As an aside, it's not clear why you're converting `row["Frokost"]` to a string and then parsing it. If it's an integer, I'd expect you to be able to cast directly to that in the C#. As a diagnostic step, you should also see what the value of `row["Frokost"]` actually is... perhaps it's a DBNull?

Comment: I'd also encourage you to provide a small piece of sample code that *isn't* Razor HTML to show what you're doing. This problem won't be specific to ASP.NET, so please show as simple C# code as you can that demonstrates the problem - ideally in a [mcve].

Comment: The error message `Input string was not in a correct format` is telling you everything you need to know. `start_time` or `stop_time` are strings not formatted according to what SQL Server's current [`DATEFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) setting requires.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - that error message doesn't appear to be from *SQL* but rather from .NET.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point, I totally missed that. Hmm, I wonder if the result set contains two `Frokost` columns, then, (or is `null`) and the `int.Parse()` is seeing something that's now the output of `datediff()`?

Comment: The result set can't contain two columns because DataTable coilumn names must be unique. In all likelihood @JonSkeet is right (shock, horror!) and `int.Parse("")` is being called. Thing is, it really doesn't need to be, because the data is already an int, so roundtripping it to a string and back is utterly nonsensical

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast the output of datediff in SQL, to an integer; it already is (see [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):  "returns int")

This means your data is already an int; you don't need to `ToString` then `Parse` it

Assuming row is a datarow:

```
int frokost = 0;
if(!row.IsNull("Frokost"))
   frokost = (int)row["Frokost"]; //weakly typed datarow returns frokost as int-boxed-as-object, cast it back


@if (frokost >= 1800) ...
```

Comment: Another technique is to use `Convert.ToInt32(row["Frokost"])`. I believe this handles NULL field values better.

Comment: i'm not sure i agree: Convert.ToInt32(DBNull.Value) results in a "dbnull cannot be cast to other types" exception in my experience. https://dotnetfiddle.net/m42n8r